# Is there any way to safely execute user's Javascript with pre-defined object & functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web-worker, worklet

Our web application is a mobile app builder. You can imagine it's like Wordpress, but the output are mobile apps. Inside the web app, we have a feature that take in user's Typescript (through Monaco Editor), transpile it and that Javascript code can be executed on the mobile app in order to display some piece of data like current user's email, a row value from database or do something on the mobile app eg. open new page, enable an input, create new data row, etc.

To make that happend, we're pre-defined a bunch of interfaces and functions, add code completion support by using Monaco's [addExtraLib](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.typescript.LanguageServiceDefaults.html#addExtraLib). For eg:

```js
declare const haptics: Haptics
declare const currentLocale: Locale
declare const currentTimeZone: TimeZone
declare const localNotifications: LocalNotifications
declare const shareSheet: ShareSheet
declare const currentUser: AppUser

declare function showAlert(
    title: string | undefined,
    message: string,
    actions: AlertAction[],
): void
```

On the execution side, on the mobile app, basically it's a React Native app, we choose our initial implementation is actually eval the Javascript code:

```js
const haptics = this.haptics
const currentLocale = this.currentLocale
const currentTimeZone = this.currentTimeZone
const localNotifications = this.localNotifications
const shareSheet = this.shareSheet
const applicationArgs = {
            showAlert,
            currentLocale,
            currentTimeZone,
            currentUser,
            localNotifications,
            openPage,
            haptics,
            shareSheet,
}

const allArgs = [...contextArgs, ...Object.entries(applicationArgs)]
const argsNames = allArgs.map(([key]) => key)
const formulaArgs = allArgs.map(([, value]) => value)
const resolvedFunc = new Function(
    ...argsNames,
    `return async function action() {${formulaString}}()`,
)
const result = await resolvedFunc(...formulaArgs)
```

This works fine. But now we have 2 concerns:

1. This need to be executed off JS' main thread, cause the script might be long-taking and blocking.
2. On the web version of the app (yes, we're using react-native-web to make the mobile app available as an PWA), owners of the app cannot execute malicious scripts that harmful or stealing user's data, starting with cookies and storages.

We've been thinking about Worklets on the React Native app, Web Worker or iframe on the web app to execute the script. But the problems are, we cannot pass those pre-defined objects and functions to these isolated threads, since `postMessage` are limited and can only post primitively types or cannot clone functions.

So here I am to ask the question and looking for a new perspective on this problem to make it work safely and accurately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "owners of the app" mean? Really if someones builds and distributes an app, they can build a malicious app, nothing you can do against that (other than not get your name associated with it).

Comment: @Bergi owners of the app means user using our platforms. They build their apps; hence they owned it. So, if they have access to javascript, nothing we can do against that?

Comment: Who will be using those apps? Who will be deploying the apps to an app store? If the owners control the release process, they could always add malicious code on top of your app anyway, so there would be no reason to restrict what they can do with your platform.